# Python kivy initialize Widget

Tags: python, kivy

I cant initialize MDTextField widget

My code:

```
class SettingsScreen(Screen):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
                super().__init__(**kwargs)
                
                self.scr = MDScreen()
                box = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=['10dp', '30dp', '10dp', '50dp'])
                imagebox = MDBoxLayout(size=(350,350), size_hint=(None,None), pos_hint={'center_x':.5})
                blur = EffectWidget()
                blur.add_widget(FitImage(source='makeblur.png'))
                blur.effects =[HorizontalBlurEffect(size=10), VerticalBlurEffect(size=10)]
                profpic = FitImageButton(source='prof.png', radius=[250, 0], on_release=self.iii)
                self.scr.add_widget(blur)
                imagebox.add_widget(profpic)
                box.add_widget(imagebox)
                box.add_widget(Widget(size_hint=(None, None), height='25dp'))
                username = Label(text='name', font_name='bebas-neue-bold.ttf', size_hint_y=None, height=5)
                box.add_widget(username)
                box.add_widget(MDBoxLayout(size_hint=(None,None)))
                profileinfo = MDScreen(md_bg_color=[1,1,1,1])
                profileinfo.add_widget(Label(size_hint=(.5, .1), pos_hint={"center_x":.6, "center_y":.8}, text='www'))
                profileinfo.add_widget(Label(text='Contact Data', color=[.1,.1,.1,1], pos=(-300,465),  font_name='bebas-neue-bold.ttf'))
                profileinfo.add_widget(Label(text='Email', color=[.1,.1,.1,1], pos=(-330,345),  font_name='bebas-neue-bold.ttf'))
                
                
                
                profileinfo.add_widget(profileinfo)
                self.scr.add_widget(box)
                
                self.add_widget(profileinfo)
                

                
                
        def iii(self, *args):
                print('www')
                selectimage = MDBoxLayout(md_bg_color=[1, 1, 1, 1], orientation='vertical')

                

        def change_screen(self, event):
                self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                self.manager.current = 'menu'
                
sm = ScreenManager()

sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        return sm

DemoApp().run()
```

I gets this error: "KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading "
ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. See https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App#exceptions
Help

Comment: Try not instantiating any widgets until the build method of your app class

Comment: okay, but im begginer

Comment: and what can i do?

Comment: Try moving the three lines that create/use `sm` into the `build()` method.